# Flutter ios release build cannot find snapshot

Tags: flutter

While trying to build flutter ios app for release I am getting this error every time

```
Failed to find snapshot: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/19D78607-A03B/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
```

I have tried these things to correct it but failed

1. running flutter clean and then flutter run --release
2. changing flutter channel to beta and master
3. deleting build folder and then flutter clean and flutter run --release
4. flutter clean > flutter build ios > archive in Xcode to test on the test flight

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing this issue frequently over the last few days. I recreated my ios directory which fixed the issue temporarily, but it came back.

What I learned is that it is expected that kernel_blob.bin is not present in release builds, because that file contains your Dart sources in bytecode form ready for JIT, but release builds don't use JIT, they use AOT and your Dart files are compiled into a binary that is placed under App.framework. Rather, this error happens because the release build of the app is incorrectly incorporating the debug (i.e. JIT) version of the Flutter engine.

The best solution I've found so far is to move the build folder to the trash (flutter clean is not working and hangs indefinitely on deleting the build folder for some reason), run flutter clean, run flutter build ios --release from the command line first, then (in my case) create the archive in Xcode.

Run flutter doctor -v

Comment: just a copy pasted answer from  here 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33292
Not helpful

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem, if someone happened, you can try this.

Remove Flutter.framework, build again. Make sure Flutter.framework and App.framework are the same debug or release mode.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following from a terminal, this removes "ios/Flutter/App.framework" and everything underneath it:

```
rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework
```

and then rebuild your app from xCode. This solved this problem for me.

Comment: After running this Xcode is showing new error
 "ld: framework not found App"